# Issue with iOS mobile browser not scrolling to the top after a route change

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, reactjs

As mentioned in the title, on iOS mobile browsers(safari, chrome), the scroll doesn't go to the top after a route change.

Below is the sample code.

```
// index.tsx
import { CSSProperties } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const styles: Record<string, CSSProperties> = {
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    gap: 12,
  }
};

export default function Home() {
  const { push } = useRouter();
  const pushToLoremPage = () => {
    push('/lorem');
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      {Array(30).fill(0).map((_, index) => (
        <span
          key={index}
          onClick={pushToLoremPage}
        >
          {`${index + 1}. Go to lorem page`}
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// LoremPage.tsx
import { useEffect, CSSProperties } from "react";

const styles: Record<string, CSSProperties> = {
    container: {
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        position: 'relative'
    },
    highlighter: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        height: '1rem',
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    lorem: {
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0
    },
};

export default function LoremPage() {
    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={styles.container}>
            <div style={styles.highlighter}></div>
            <p style={styles.lorem}>
                {/* lorem */}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that when navigating from the index page, which has been scrolled down, to the LoremPage, the same scroll position is applied to the LoremPage.

To be precise, the issue occurs only when transitioning from the index page with a very slight scroll down to the Lorem page. (In this scenario, it seems that window.scrollTo(0, 0) doesn't have an effect.)

Below images are describe three situations.(left: index page, right: Lorem page).
***Please attention 3rd image**

#### 1. without scrolling

[image: without scroll]

#### 2. with normal scroll

[image: normal scroll]

#### 3. with slight scroll

[image: slight scroll]

For reference, the same issue wasn't observed on the Android Chrome browser.

Also, no CSS has been applied(except example codes), and this issue occurs with both Next.js and React Router on boilerplate-level code.

trying:
(at LoremPage.tsx)

```
useEffect(() => {
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, [])
```

expecting:
scroll to top after route change with slight scrolling.